# Is there a way of assigning multiple variables to elements in a named R list in one line?

Tags: r, list

I would like to assign variables to elements in a named list. These variable names are the same as the names in the list. Is there a way that I can assign them all in one line instead of one at a time like what I am doing below?

```
 params <- data[data$Month == m,]

  a <- params$a
  b <- params$b
  c <- params$c
```

I know that in Java Script you can destructure and array like so:

```
const [a, b, c] =[1,2,3]
```

Or a dictionary (which is perhaps more similar to an R named list):

```
const {a, b, c} = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
```

Each of these assign the variables a,b and c to the values 1,2 and 3 respectively.

Is there a similar approach that I can take with R?

Comment: You should `dput` example data and specify expected output to clarify what you want, please consult our R-tag guidelines before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038

Answer (score 1):

Use `list2env` to create individual objects for each column in `params`.

```
params <- data[data$Month == m,]
list2env(params, .GlobalEnv)
```

If you want to keep data in a named list use `as.list`.

```
as.list(params)
```

Answer (score 1):

Establish a named list (lst) in advance. Then you can assign the variables in the data frame (params) in one line.

```
lst <- vector(mode="list", length = 3)
lst <- list(params$a,params$b,params$c)
names(lst) <- c("a","b","c")
```